# My navbar (hamburger) menu disaapear while :hover

Tags: css, responsive-design, nav

im trying to make some navbar in hamburger style, and while I :hover that hamburger the ul (the menu actually) open, but while trying to choose one of my li it disappear . I would like to get some help im new with css/html. thank you very much <3 peace

```css
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      list-style: none;   
    }
    nav {         
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    nav .logo {                 
      line-height: 2;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    nav img {
      width: 2em;
      position: absolute;
      right: 2em;
      top: 1.5em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    nav ul {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 20px;        
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      display: none;          
    }
    nav ul li {
      margin-top: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 5;
    }
    nav ul li a {         
      font-size: 1.3em;          
    }
    nav ul li a:hover {
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
    img:hover+.openw {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
  <nav class="nav">
    <label for="" class="logo">DesignX</label>
    <img src="240.png" alt="">

    <ul class="openw">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You didn't post your  html. please show us.

Comment: we need html to test and help you

Comment: I cant add my html is says that the most of my post is a code, what to do? I add it here but for the next time <body>

  <nav class="nav">
    <label for="" class="logo">DesignX</label>
    <img src="/HTML/31_5/HW/iconmonstr-menu-1-240.png" alt="">

    <ul class="openw">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>